# Django validate column combination existence (Unique with boolean field)

Tags: python, django, validation, model

I'm on Django 1.9. I've a simple model with:

```
#Goods
class Goods(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    decription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...etc

#Vendors
class Vendors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...etc
```

And a class to define the multiple vendors to obtain a good.

```
#Purchase_options
class PurchaseOptions(models.Model):
    preferred_vendor = models.BooleanField()
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendors)
    good = models.ForeignKey(Goods)
```

**Here's is the question:**
How can I make sure that **only one** vendor for a particular good can be set as preferred?.

Accepted values on table:

```
**Vendor | Product | Preferred**
  V_01   | Good_01 | True
  V_02   | Good_01 | False
  V_03   | Good_01 | False
  V_02   | Good_02 | True
  V_04   | Good_02 | False
```

Wrong values on table:

```
**Vendor | Product | Preferred**
  V_01   | Good_01 | True
  V_02   | Good_01 | **True**  <-There's already a preferred vendor.
  V_03   | Good_01 | False
  V_02   | Good_02 | True
  V_04   | Good_02 | False
```

I'm using Django's admin interface to fill-up the data on Puchase_Options.
I tried this:

1) Define a validator that, given the Preferred value and the product id, checks if this combination exists in the table:

```
def validator(preferred, id):
    if Purchase_Option.objects.filter(good.id=id,preferred_vendor=preferred).exists():
        Raise ValidationError("There's already a preferred vendor defined for this product")
```

But it's telling me that object Purchase_Options doesn't exist. I believe I can't actually query the database or handle querysets within a validator function.

2) I tried using the meta property **unique-together("preferred_vendor","good_id")**. That would work except that I must allow multiple combinations of **False + Good_Id** (because I've many Non-Preferred vendors for a good)... but only just 1 combination of **True+Good_id.**

I don't really know what else to try and I'm really looking forward to hearing your ideas. You saved me in multiple occasions before :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for `preferred_vendor`, and [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for `preferred_vendor` and `good`. Use `True` for the one preferred vendor and `NULL` instead of `False` for all others.

This will allow you to have multiple pair of (`good`, `NULL`) and only one pair with (`good`,`True`). The drawback is you will be able to also have only one pair (`good`,`False`), but this shouldn't be a problem.

E.g.:

```
class PurchaseOptions(models.Model):
    preferred_vendor = models.NullBooleanField()
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendors)
    good = models.ForeignKey(Goods)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("preferred_vendor", "good")
```

then:

```
  Vendor | Product | Preferred
  V_01   | Good_01 | True
  V_02   | Good_01 | NULL
  V_03   | Good_01 | NULL
  V_02   | Good_02 | True
  V_04   | Good_02 | NULL
```

Comment: Nikita, your approach works. So I'm really thankful for that. I'll leave the question running for a little more time to allow any other alternative, although I'm satisfied with yours. Why is it that the combination of good and null isn't a duplicate?. I really don't get it.

Comment: Great that it helps! Actually, I didn't researched if your question is a duplicate, I just came up with an idea and posted it. So may be there is some similar question, but if not, then this will definitely help others.

Comment: No buddy, don't get me wrong.. i'm not telling that your answer is a duplicate, maybe I didn't express myself correctly.. I mean in terms of SQL and Django... Why does True+Good and False + Good allow only one combination but the NULL+Good allows multiple combinations.. I simply don't get it. Thanks!!!

Comment: I see, it's said that any `NULL` is considered not equal to other `NULL`'s, so it can be used in unique constrains. But allowing `NULL` as unique might be an implementation feature, i.e. database dependent, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks man... I'll mark your answer as good. Have a great day.